# jquery input value to <p>

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm sure this had been asked a lot of times, but I truly can't find an answer here or google, that fits into my needs.

I got a form with an input text-field. I want this value to appear in `<p>` after submit.
s.th like that, just without keyup, but submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").keyup(function () {
         var value = $(this).val();
         $("p").text(value);
         })

})
```

HTML is

```
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" value="" size=20 id="write"/>
</form>
<p> </p>
</body>
```

anyone who knows?

thanks in advance

Comment: <body>

<form>
<input type="text" value="" size=20 id="write"/>
</form>

<p> </p>

</body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind to the submit event. I would also suggest adding id's to the form, input, and p elements that are involved.  So you could end up with something like:

```
$('#form_id').submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#p_id').text($('#input_id').val());
});
```

And revised HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="form_id">
<input id="input_id" type="text" value="" size=20 id="write"/>
</form>
<p id="p_id"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: tried this and gave the html the correct id's, but unfortunately it does not work

  $("#test").submit(function () {
   $("#text").text($('#test').val())
   })

Comment: @ChristophHa Well I noticed your HTML doesn't have a submit button.  Did you actually submit the form?

Comment: I thought about to submit just by pushing enter

Comment: great this works out very well, but must be done, that the text will no go away after a short second?

Comment: You can use `preventDefault()` on the submit event.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

With this html

```
<form id="formId" onsubmit="submitHandler()">
    <input id="inputId" type="text" value="" size=20 />
</form>
<p id="pId"></p>
```

You could do it like this

```
function submitHandler() {
    $('#pId').html($('#inputId').val());
    return false; //if you don't want it to be processed any further
}
```